# CSS - having search suggestion box border/background disappear while empty

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/scomiller/pen/jEQEdX

```
#suggestions {
font: bold 14px/25px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
float: right;
width: 300px;
margin-top: -55px;
margin-right: 460px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #EEE;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

As shown here I have a search box and when you type something in beginning with C, such as CIS lab, or just CIS, a list of suggestions come up on the right hand side. If you notice, there's a grey box behind that resizes to the contents listed, however, when the search box is cleared or simply empty, there's still a small box there. How can I make it so if the suggestion is not currently active, there is no background?

Answer (score 0):

use `:empty`

```
#suggestion {
    display: none;
}
#suggestions:not(:empty) {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware a pseudo class would work for that. That works if I type sometime and then backspace it to an empty string or just hit the clear button, but when the page initally loads the box is still there. Is there a way around that.

Comment: Then change it around. Make it `#suggestion { display: none; }` 
 and `#suggestions:not(:empty) { display: block; }`.
In other word - hide by default, and show when NOT empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class:

```css
#suggestions:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

To make it work, you will have to remove all content (including whitespaces) inside `#suggestions`:

```html
<div id="suggestions"></div>
```

```js
var hints = ["c#",
  "c++",
  "call by copy",
  "call by name",
  "call by reference",
  "career",
  "carlson",
  "cascading style sheet",
  "case",
  "catch",
  "c++ book",
  "c++ class",
  "c++ classes",
  "c++ compiler",
  "c++ debugger",
  "c++ documentation",
  "cellpadding",
  "cell padding",
  "cellspacing",
  "cell spacing",
  "certification",
  "c++ exception",
  "c++ function",
  "c++ programming",
  "char",
  "character array",
  "choice",
  "cin",
  "cis",
  "cis alumni",
  "cis assessment",
  "cis class schedule",
  "cis course descriptions",
  "cis courses",
  "cis course schedule",
  "cis department",
  "cis department chairperson",
  "cis department faculty",
  "cisdept",
  "cis dept",
  "cis dept faculty",
  "cis dept policies",
  "cis faculty",
  "cis lab",
  "cis lab hours",
  "cis lab information",
  "cis lab schedule",
  "cis major",
  "cis minor",
  "cis tutors",
  "class",
  "classes",
  "class function",
  "class schedule",
  "click handler",
  "close",
  "clp",
  "c++ object",
  "c++ objects",
  "c-string",
  "code reuse",
  "coding",
  "coding error",
  "color",
  "command line argument",
  "comment",
  "comparison",
  "compound condition",
  "computer",
  "computer and network security",
  "computer architecture",
  "computer architecture and operating systems",
  "computer organization",
  "computer science",
  "computer science project",
  "computer science concentration",
  "computer security",
  "computing",
  "computing and information science",
  "computing and information science major",
  "computing career",
  "computing department",
  "computing dept",
  "computing faculty",
  "computing home page",
  "computing jobs",
  "computing major",
  "computing science project",
  "condition",
  "const",
  "constant",
  "constant function",
  "constructor",
  "container class",
  "conversion",
  "cookie",
  "copy constructor",
  "count",
  "count-controlled loop",
  "course",
  "course descriptions",
  "course schedule",
  "cout",
  "c++ pointer",
  "c++ program",
  "c++ programming",
  "cs concentration",
  "css",
  "c++ stream",
  "c style string",
  "c-style string",
  "ctrl z",
  "c++ tutorial",
  "curriculum"
];

function suggest(str) {
  var currentHint, location, temp;
  var domSuggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions"); // Get a reference to the div whose id is suggestions.

  cleanup();

  for (k = 0; k < hints.length; k++) {
    currentHint = hints[k]; // Get the string at index k in the hints array. 

    if (isPrefix(str, currentHint)) // Call isPrefix on str and currentHint to see if the letters of str match the beginning of currentHint.
    {
      temp = '<a onclick="useSuggestion(' + k + ')" >' + currentHint + '</a><br />';
      domSuggestions.innerHTML = domSuggestions.innerHTML + temp; // Adds a clickable word or phrase to the innerHTML of the div.
    }
  }
  if (str == "") {
    cleanup();
  }
}


function isPrefix(s, hint) {
  var k;
  var sLen = s.length;
  var hintLen = hint.length;

  if (sLen > hintLen)
    return false;

  s = s.toLowerCase();

  for (k = 0; k < sLen; k++) {
    if (s[k] != hint[k]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true; // All of s matched the start of hint.
}


function cleanup() {
  var domSuggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
  domSuggestions.innerHTML = ""; // Put the empty string in as the innerHTML of the div whose id is suggestions.
}


function useSuggestion(hint) {
  document.getElementById("Key1").value = hints[hint]; // Put hints[hint] in as the value of the input text box whose id is Key1.
}


function validate(thisform) {
  cleanup();

  if (thisform.Key1.value == "") {
    alert("No keyword or phrase was entered.  Please try again.");
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
}
```

```css
/*Header text syling*/

h2 {
  margin-top: 35px;
  background-color: #85D0FF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font: bold 25px/40px'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}
.title {
  margin-left: 400px;
}
/*Search information/directions styling*/

ul {
  margin-top: 35px;
  font: 13px/17px'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
  opacity: 0.6;
  list-style-type: square;
}
/*Optional hiding/opacity change for above directions*/

/*ul:hover {
opacity: 0.9;
}*/

/*Search box styling*/

.searchbox {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
/*Location and styling of the pop-up suggestions*/

#suggestions {
  font: bold 14px/25px'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: -55px;
  margin-right: 460px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#suggestions:empty {
  display: none;
}
/*Styling and transformation of the suggestions pre-hover*/

a {
  background-color: #85D0FF;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
/*Styling and transformation of the suggestions during cursor hover*/

a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 100%;
}
/*Adds content to the beginning of a suggestion during mouse-over*/

a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 75%;
}
/*Header style*/

h2 {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/*Search and Clear button styling*/

.button {
  margin-top: -5px;
  /*This margin works best with search autocomplete turned off*/
  font: bold 14px/40px'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #8A8A8A;
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  float: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 63px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*Aligns text in center of button*/
}
/*Search and Clear button hover styling*/

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  zoom: 1.05;
}
.footer {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
/*Footer styling (mainly for the Br. David Carlson link*/

.footer:hover {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<h2>CIS Department Search</h2>
<ul>
  <li>The search term you put in the input box below can be a word or phrase.</li>
  <li>The search engine will look for an exact match for what you put in a box, so spelling matters.</li>
  <li>Search terms generally have to be at least 3 characters long, but a few common search terms such as C# and += that have length 2 are allowed.</li>
  <li>Search terms should generally be in the singular, not the plural, but plurals of a few very common search terms are accepted.</li>
  <li>The search is not case-sensitive.</li>
</ul>
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/uncgi/search205" onsubmit="return validate(this)" onreset="cleanup()">
  <p>
    <input type="text" class="searchbox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Keyword or phrase" id="Key1" name="Key1" size="56" maxlength="56" onkeyup="suggest(this.value)" />
  </p>
  <div id="suggestions"></div>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
    <input type="reset" class="button" value="Clear" />
  </p>
</form>
<small>Search engine written by Julian Whalen, Josh Vasko, and
  <a class="footer" href="/carlsond/index.html">Br. David Carlson</A>
</small>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is nice to know. I was a bit confused of what you meant by removing all content including whitespaces in #suggestions, but it seems to work, except initially when the page loads.

Comment: @idlehand I meant that `<div id="suggestions">   </div>` has some spaces inside, so `:empty` wouldn't work. The same applies to line breaks, tabs, etc. It must be `<div id="suggestions"></div>`.